# How to avoid any phpstan errors with try / catch block in the end of the function?

Tags: laravel, phpstan

On laravel 10 site running phpstan on method

```
    /**
     * Retrieve user getItemss related to getItems by $itemId
     *
     * param int $itemId - getItems id
     *
     * @return JsonResponse with collection of found data,
     *
     */
    public function getItems(int $itemId): JsonResponse
    {
        try {
            return response()->json([
                'data' => ItemResource::collection($this->itemRepository->getItems(id: $itemId))
            ], JsonResponse::HTTP_OK); // 200
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Item # "' . $itemId . '" not found',
            ], JsonResponse::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            \Log::info($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

But I have error pointing at try block line:

> ```
>  Method App\Http\Controllers\Api\ItemController::getItems() should return Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse but return statement is missing.
> ```

Not sure what have I return under last catch and in the end of the function to avoid any  phpstan errors ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.34.2",
"nunomaduro/larastan": "^2.6.4",
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are not returning from all of the possible paths (you could end up in the last catch and since there is no return there you would end up at the end of the function, which has no return) ... so return what you are supposed to from all possible paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static typing means your function should always return the type you specified no matter what the input value or path it takes, in your case, your method `getItems` always expect to return `JsonResponse` regardless of its internal logic, the end result must be `JsonResponse` type,

problem is when your 2nd catch block is hit, it does not return anything (just returns void)

you could simply just do something like;

```
public function getItems(int $itemId): JsonResponse {
    
    $message = 'Something wrong!';
    $code = JsonResponse::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    try {
        return response()->json([
            'data' => ItemResource::collection($this->itemRepository->getItems(id: $itemId))
        ], JsonResponse::HTTP_OK); 

    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        $message = "Item # $itemId not found";
        $code = 404;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        \Log::info($e->getMessage());
        $message =  $e->getMessage();
    }

    return response()->json( [
        'message' => $message 
    ], $code); 
}
```

**To avoid unused variables**

```
public function getItems(int $itemId): JsonResponse {

    try {
        return response()->json([
            'data' => ItemResource::collection($this->itemRepository->getItems(id: $itemId))
        ], JsonResponse::HTTP_OK); 

    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        $message = "Item # $itemId not found";
        $code = 404;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        \Log::info($e->getMessage());
        $message =  $e->getMessage();
        $code = JsonResponse::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }

    return response()->json( [
        'message' => $message 
    ], $code); 

}
```

another option with single return statement at the end of the function, and just mutating the variable inside try/catch block

```
public function getItems(int $itemId): JsonResponse {

    $res = [ 'data' => null, 'message' => '' ];
    $code = JsonResponse::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    try {
        $res['data'] = ItemResource::collection($this->itemRepository->getItems(id: $itemId));
        $code = JsonResponse::HTTP_OK;
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        $res['message'] = "Item # $itemId not found";
        $code = 404;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        \Log::info($e->getMessage());
        $res['message'] =  $e->getMessage();
    }

    return response()->json( $res, $code); 
    
}
```

or with each block has return statement no variables defined!

```
public function getItems(int $itemId): JsonResponse {

    try {
        return response()->json([
            'data' => ItemResource::collection($this->itemRepository->getItems(id: $itemId))
        ], 200); 
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        return response()->json([ 'message' => "Item # $itemId not found" ], 404); 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([ 'message' => $e->getMessage() ], 500); 
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you! in this flow phpstan shown no errors. But now my phpstorm shows declarations of $message and $code vars at top of the function as unused (in grayed color).
    I set $code(with default value = JsonResponse::HTTP_OK) into the first return response()->json( - so $code is not grayed anymore, but $message var is still unused...
    Do you see my point ?

Comment: you can also just initialize the `$res` at the top with empty array like `$res = [ ];`